# Can not define more than 10 style rules for TFS 2017 Tasks board

Tags: tfs

In Task boards of our TFS 2017 (Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.131.28601.4) I see the message that I can not add more than 10 style rules and I dont know where this settings has come from :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a user configured setting, it's a **system limitation**. Same on Azure DevOps 2019 latest version and Azure DevOps Service.

When you added 9 style rules, you will see this promote message: `you can add up to 10 style rules tfs`

When you added 10 style rules, you will not able to add any new style rules, the "+" button will also turn gray.

[image]

If you wan to add a new style rule. You have to delete a redundant style rule, choose the  actions icon [image] and select  Delete. There is not any configuration to expand this limitation.

Comment: A very bad limitation IMO, specially for big teams having customized tfs board.